# Flake8 in VS Code: unused imports not underlined

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, flake8

I've installed Flake8 using Anaconda prompt, to an environment I'm using. I'm using VS Code.

I recently used the terminal in VS Code to tell Flake8 to ignore certain errors and I think one of them was F401, which concerns unused imports.

It's very clear how to ignore a given error, but I can't find anything about how to "unignore" it.

I know Flake8 is working in my environment because other errors are given squiggly underlines in VS Code.

**How can I make the squiggly underlines reappear for F401?**

NB. I'm unable to locate the config file discussed in the Flake8 documentation. If I could do so, I imagine I'd just be able to delete the line about ignoring F401. I couldn't find out how to locate the config file that's being applied when I call flake8 from VS Code. (As far as I can tell the documentation only tells you how to create a overriding config file.)

Comment: do you have flake8 configured in `.flake8` or `setup.cfg` or `tox.ini` or `~/.flake8`?

Comment: @AnthonySottile The problem -- please forgive my ignorance -- is that I don't know how to figure that out. I can say for certain that there's no `~/.flake8` in my "top level user directory", and within the project I'm working on there's no `.flake8` or `setup.cfg` or `tox.ini`. I was hoping I could run a command in the VS Code terminal to find out where (in the particular environment I'm working in) flake8 is getting it's settings from.

Comment: you could use `flake8 -vvvv path/to/file.py`

Comment: @AnthonySottile Hi Anthony -- Thanks for getting back to me. I ran the command you suggested, and searched the output for F401 -- there were no hits. I was also unable to locate the location of the configuration in the output. Are you aware of a more precise command I can run? If not, I can run flake8 in the terminal and manually view the errors to remove unused packages. Many thanks.

Comment: @AnthonySottile I did find this: `Extended default select list: ['C90', 'F']`. And F401 starts with an F...

Comment: is your file being excluded maybe? it would mention F401 and then that it's ignoring it if it detected it

Comment: @AthonySottile No, unfortunately not... Perhaps it's a genuine bug. Though I'm always strongly inclined to believe I'm doing something stupid.

Comment: can you paste the entire log and the contents of the file you expect to have failures? use a pastebin service and post the links here?

Comment: @AnthonySottile Thankfully I was able to solve the problem (see my "answer" below) -- user error as expected! Thanks again for your help. Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an extension called `cornflakes-linter` and had forgotten to update the path to the flake8 executable.

In more detail:

1. Located flake8 executable with the command `where flake8` in the VS Code terminal.
2. Added the following to my `settings.json`:

   ```
   "cornflakes.linter.executablePath": "path/to/venvs/myvenv/bin/flake8"
   ```

I found the relevant documentation here:

https://github.com/kevinglasson/vscode-cornflakes-linter